# Weird interpretation of $\frac{\delta x}{x}$?

Tags: derivatives, physics

In *Problem 1, section A4* of [this exam paper](http://panpearl.phys.ust.hk/files/pastpaper_sol/PanPearl-2018-test-2_solution.pdf), the solution given below seem to use the fact that
$$y\propto x^{\alpha} \Longrightarrow \frac{\delta y}{y} = \alpha \frac{\delta x}{x}$$
where $x$ and $y$ are two variables.

Not only is the meaning of $\delta$ ambiguous, I cannot find such usage online. What does the $\delta$ symbol mean here and why is the above statement correct?

Comment: If $y=Cx^\alpha$ then $dy/dx = C\alpha x^{\alpha-1}= \alpha y/x$ which gives rise to your equation if you treat dy and dx as ordinary numbers $\delta y$ and $\delta x$ and rearrange. That's the kind of thing physicists do informally so probably it's what is happening here.

Comment: $\delta y,\delta x$ are small changes in $y$ resp. in $x$. If the equals sign is taken as $\approx$ it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, $\delta x$ is notation for "a small change in $x$", and represents a quantity that is small relative to the actual value of $x$.

The statement $y \propto x^\alpha \implies \frac{\delta y}{y} \approx \alpha \frac{\delta x}{x}$ (note the approximately equal sign) can be found using either a Taylor series or a binomial expansion, for example:

$$\begin{eqnarray} y & \propto & x^\alpha \\
y & = & k x^\alpha \\
(y + \delta y) & = & k (x + \delta x)^\alpha \\
y \left( 1 + \frac{\delta y}{y} \right) & = & k x^\alpha \left(1 + \frac{\delta x}{x}\right)^\alpha \\
& = & k x^\alpha \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {\alpha \choose n}\left(\frac{\delta x}{x} \right)^n \\
& = & k x^\alpha \left(1 + \alpha \frac{\delta x}{x} + \frac{\alpha (\alpha - 1)}{2}\left(\frac{\delta x}{x} \right)^2 + \ldots \right) \\
& = & k x^\alpha\left(1 + \alpha \frac{\delta x}{x} + O\left(\left(\frac{\delta x}{x} \right)^2\right) \right) \\
k x^\alpha \left(1 + \frac{\delta y}{y}\right) & \approx & k x^\alpha \left(1 + \alpha \frac{\delta x}{x} \right) & \mbox{when } \frac{\delta x}{x} \mbox{ is small} \\
\implies \frac{\delta y}{y} & \approx & \alpha \frac{\delta x}{x}
\end{eqnarray}$$

where $\alpha \choose n$ is the [generalised binomial coefficient](https://planetmath.org/generalizedbinomialcoefficients), and $O\left(\left(\frac{\delta x}{x}\right)^2\right)$ represents a collection of terms that are bounded by some constant multiple of $\left(\frac{\delta x}{x}\right)^2$ as $\delta x \rightarrow 0$, i.e. if $\delta x$ is "small enough" the error in the approximation is ignorable, and in fact it vanishes entirely in the limit.